# I saw Tom back at the last gas station

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> I saw Tom back at the last gas station.

Why 'back' is here? Is this again? or the gas statin is at the back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In every day speech, **back** is used in conversation between two people to locate a place to the rear of a speaker.

Let's imagine that you and I are driving in a car, discussing (poor) Tom. I could say to you: I saw Tom back at the filling station. That implies that the gas station is behind you on the road.

If you are walking on the street with someone and talking, the same would apply:

"I saw him back at the apartment." The use of back like here emphasizes the location where Tom was last seen by you.

It can also be used **for time:**

"I saw him back in 2004 but haven't seen him since."

back is sometime accompanied by the word way: way back at the gas station or way back in 2004. way back means even farther back.

The semantic idea here is that you are on a path going somewhere and back refers to a place or time that someone, including, yourself have been before the conversation you are having.

It is colloquial speech, idiomatic speech, it is not non-standard at all. Spoken English is not written English. It is a spoken English marker in spoken English.

Answer (score 2):

The word "back" is fairly redundant.  It is used because Tom was "back there".  The last (ie most recently visited) gas station is behind the speaker, so it is at the back of the speaker (relative to their direction of travel.

The expression is fully idiomatic.

Comment: you mean it's both: 1. Tom was back from somewhere and also 2. the last station is back (relative to their direciton of travel)

Comment: No just back behind the speaker.  Tom might not have returned from anywhere in particular.

Answer (score 0):

It is not careful English.  *Back* is unnecessary here.  It can be elided with no loss of meaning whatsoever.

In America, this kind of English is spoken by some people in rural areas--with a [twang](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/twang). It is also spoken in some urban areas.

*Where you at* is the same sort of thing.  It is not careful English.

For example:

### A Conversation on the Phone

Fred:  Hello?

Mike:  Hey, it's Mike.  Where you at?

Fred:  I'm at the market.

Mike:  I just saw Tom back at the gas station.

Fred:  Yeah?

Mike:  You see him, you tell him he owes me fifty bucks.

Fred:  OK, bye!

Comment: As a speaker of AmE, I find this answer to be very odd. Putting at, at the end of where is x, is not a rural thing. And the use of back here is definitely not non-standard. It is also not a filler word per se.

Comment: @Lambie  You are right to some extent, I think.  I should edit my answer and say it in a better way.